# Find frame in window of collection view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm getting all the visible cells in a `UICollectionViewController` like this.

```
NSArray<__kindof UICollectionViewCell *> *cells = [self.collectionView.visibleCells visibleCells];
```

How do I find the frame for the cell in the window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

**Swift**

```
guard
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: yourVisibleCell),
    let attributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
    else {
        assertionFailure("Can't get required attributes")
        return
}

let frameInWindow = collectionView.convert(attributes.frame, to: nil)
```

**Objective C**

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:yourVisibleCell];

UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *theAttributes = [collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath];

CGRect cellFrameInSuperview = [collectionView convertRect:theAttributes.frame toView:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks!  It works just doing `[collectionView convertRect:yourVisibleCell.frame toView: collectionView.superview.superview]` too.

Comment: Pass `nil` as the `toView:` parameter to convert to the window's coordinates. No need to figure out the right ancestor view.

Comment: @ken Great to know about the nil concept.  Thanks for notifying

Answer (score 0):

Xcode friendly Swift variant of iPrabu's answer:

```
var screenCellFrame: CGRect? {
    if let cell = <#visibleCell#>, let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell), let attributes = collectionView!.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) {
        return collectionView!.convert(attributes.frame, to: nil)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```